# SFTP to a host that can only be connected through SSH Bastion in Windows (Putty)

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, putty, sftp

I don't even know how to explain this and the title might also be incorrect. But this is what I am trying to do,

I use an SFTP plugin Sublime Text which connects to by dev machine (lets call it D) and syncs the files on save.

When I am working from home, I cannot connect to my dev machine due to obvious security reasons. I have to connect to a bastion host (lets call it S) and then from S I have to ssh to D. This is cool, now I can run commands and use Vim.

However is there a way I could open up the SFTP port for my local machine to connect or the plugin to work. I think its called SSH Tunnel but I am not sure how do I do it.

The plugin makes use of <strike>Putty and</strike> Pageant (for ssh key) to connect/sync files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use port forwarding for this.

Lets say the machine you can connect to is on `88.88.88.88` and that is the public address of your server on `10.8.8.8`.  The machine you want to get to is on `10.8.8.9`

You connect to the first machine with ssh, and set up a port forward to the next. I'll show the command line way so that you can see how it works:

```
ssh -L2222:10.8.8.9:22 user@88.88.88.88
```

So this is doing a standard login to `88.88.88.88` but the -L switch is saying "set up port `2222` on my local machine, and anything that goes to it should be tunnelled to `88.88.88.88` and from there sent on to `10.8.8.9` on port `22`"

So now you can do this on the same machine you ran the first command from, and it will connect through to the internal machine (just do the equivalent in your sftp client):

```
sftp 127.0.0.1:2222
```

To set up the port forward in putty, go to the ssh / tunnels part of the session setup.

Put `2222` in the source port, and put `10.8.8.9:22` in the destination, make sure `local` is selected, and click add.

Note that you can change these setting during an established ssh session.  So if you need another port forward you can add it here and it takes effect immediately, no need to disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: Awesome thank you. So after running the ssh command, I go back to the sublime plugin and change the hostname from remote host to 127.0.0.1 and port to 2222 ?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think Putty in my question was a little misleading. I corrected it.

Comment: @Paul I get this error when I try to run the forwarding command user@10.196.xx.x's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Although I am 100% sure the password I entered was correct.

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Sorry, I am not following this - where does the 10.196.x.x address come into it?  The first ssh connection will be to a public address, the second sftp to the localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: Sorry  let me clear it a bit, so made the first ssh connection. which worked fine. Then ran the ssh command to the actual host from inside the bastion host. It keeps asking me for password and then shows up that error  

`amohammed@88.88.88.88's password:`  

The 88.88.88.88 is a Windows machine. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Both connections above originate from the first machine - the one external to the network you are connecting to.

Comment: Still the same problem. I get a long warning message `****USAGE WARNING****  this is a personal computer bla bla bla` ..  and then it says `user@88.88.88.88's password:`

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Are you replacing 88.88.88.88 with your servers public IP?

Comment: Haha yes. Well actually it worked. For some reason I'm getting that error (maybe companys policies). But when I went into my text editor and replaced SFTP settings to 127.0.0.1 and port 2222. It worked. Thanks a lot pal!